# Laravel 5.5 Authorization, supplying additional credentials, calling retrieveByCredentials()

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, credentials, laravel-5.5

Upgrading from 4.2.  I'm trying to hook into 5.5's Auth model, and (as many people do) require additional fields (credentials).  Most people seem to simply bypass the auth structure. We'd rather 'do it properly' so to speak, and remain fully integrated in the Laravel-provided Auth features.

But I am not sure how to call **retrieveByCredentials($array)** in the login context.
(for api docs see: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.html#method_retrieveByCredentials )

So, can you help me with what to USE, and how to call the Method?

-Thanks

---

For people who want to know add credentials by overriding the AuthenticateUsers Trait, in your **LoginController()**

First, add to the top of the file:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
```

Then inside the class, at the top add:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

Then in the body of the class, add these two functions:

```
/**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{

    // NOTE: Add fields here to regulate login requirements.
    // ORIGINAL CODE: return $request->only($this->username(), 'password', 'verified');

    // CODE WITH ADDITIONAL FIELDS (you can use any syntax you want to add to the array)
    // Note that the binary '1' values are still in single quotes cover all circumstances.

    return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['verified' => '1', 'can_login' => '1']);

}


/**
 * Get the failed login response instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 *
 * @throws ValidationException
 */
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
     // MY QUESTION IS: INSTEAD OF CALLING THIS:
     $user = SysUserModel::where('email', '=', $request->email)->firstOrFail(['email','verified','can_login', 'state']);


    //HOW DO I CALL THIS? (And is this correct? Is there a better way to capture the user data without an additional call to the database?)

    $user = retrieveByCredentials( $request->only($this->username(), 'password'));

    // SO THAT I CAN DETERMINE IF 
    // (a) the user-email/pw doesn't exist
    // (b) the user-email/pw exists but 'verified' = 0
    // (c) the user-email/pw exists, 'verified' = 1, but 'can_login' = 0

    // SO THAT I CAN RETURN THE APPROPRIATE ERROR MESSAGE HERE

    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ]);


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When customizing the authentication process, you should be  implementing a custom guard. This way you're needing to alter the framework code or override anything extensively . As you can see below, the controller has a `guard` property that calls `attempt`. This is where your guard would handle the addition fields passed in.

```
/**
  * Attempt to log the user into the application.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @return bool
  */
 protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
 {
     return $this->guard()->attempt(
         $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
     );
 }
```

See here for how to implement a custom guard:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Finally, you set your new guard in `config/auth.php`

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense.  I would write a guard if I wanted to authenticate against an external system, say, like LDAP.  To extend Laravel/Mysql requires overloading the AuthenticatesUsers Trait. That's the lowest impact means of extending Laravel out of the box Auth package. 

However, that auth system uses a pass/fail rather than returning which of the credentials failed Verification, even though it returns which credentials failed Validation.

I want to determine which credential failed without an additional query without directly accessing the table.

Comment: Guards are not exclusive to external systems. Guards take an instance of a user provider in their constructors, which implement the user provider contract. Which is precisely where the `retrieveByCredentials` method you're looking at is defined. No overloading required. From the docs: `Guards define how users are authenticated for each request.` and `Providers define how users are retrieved from your persistent storage.`.

Comment: Alright. If that's how it's done that's how we'll do it.  
(Although it's no wonder it seems like everyone overrides or just circumvents it.  I don't see the value.  That's tremendous overhead . hmm...

Comment: It's really not as involved as it sounds, tbh. I recently needed to augment logging in with Facebook through Socialite. With a custom Guard and UserProvider I had it up and working in about 30 minutes. It's a clean, separated approach, controlled through the auth.php configuration and now we can apply it as needed to any route(s).

Comment: I'm still fussing over this and I gotta stick with  "It doesn't fly".  
Eloquent driver exists. Custom class for users or just modify users exist or must exist. In your login/registration Use AuthenticatesUsers, override Credentials() to add the additional credentials, override sendFailedLoginResponse() to return a message on which credentials failed. And you have near zero code impact, code to write, and test. Digging thru Auth and there is no reason can't return the credentials selected in the where clause, or throw an event we can catch.

Comment: You're free to do as you see fit. The point here being you don't see custom `login` methods per driver/provider combination by default, you simply set config and/or middleware as needed.

Comment: I see.  What you're saying is, preserver the defaults, and add something new.  I understand. It's just ... kind of silly given that the default structure doesn't include even email validation, and so ... anyway. Appreciate the advice.  -cheers